# MYSQL select maximum sum of purchases

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following Table named Order

```
Orders Table
___________________________________________________
orderiD | userId | OrderType | Order_Date | Amount
________|________|___________|____________|________
1          1          0         12/12/2009    1
2          1          1         13/12/2009    2
3          1          1         14/12/2009    3
4          2          0         12/12/2009    4
5          2          1         16/12/2009    2
6          1          0         14/12/2009    5
7          2          1         17/12/2009    4
8          2          0         10/12/2010    2
___________________________________________________
```

I need to create query which returns user id with maximum SUM of purchases.

I tried the following

```
Select MAX(GRP.sumAmmount), o.userId join
(Select SUM(o.Amount) as sum_ammount, o.userId as UID from Orders GROUP BY(o.userID)) as GRP on o.userId=GRP.UID GROUP BY(GRP.UID)
```

But I believe I'm missing something.

Can you help?

Comment: I think you have an invalid sql syntax because you are joining `GRP` from an unknown table. And I believe it id `Orders o`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to return the `UserID` which has the maximum SUM (*total*) of purchases. So the above records will result:

```
UserID  Total Amount
  2         12
```

And the simpliest solution would be:

```
SELECT UserID, SUM(AMOUNT) as TotalAmount
FROM Orders
GROUP BY UserID
ORDER BY TotalAmount DESC
LIMIT 1
```

I'm ready to edit this if I'm wrong. :-) 
 (*PS: Please add your desired result*)
 
Thanks.

**UPDATE 1**

Derived from you query:

```
  Select  MAX(SUM(o.Amount)) as sum_ammount, 
          o.userId as UID 
    FROM  Orders o
GROUP BY  o.userID
ORDER BY  sum_ammount DESC
   LIMIT  1
```

Comment: you downvoted me... right?? Don't worry I will upvote you... :)

Comment: Unfortunately, second query does not work it brings exactly the same result as  Select SUM(o.Amount) as sum_ammount, 
               o.userId as UID 
        FROM   Orders o
        GROUP BY (o.userID)

Comment: did the first query answers your question? I just updated my second query.

Comment: This will not handle more than one user having the same max sum.

Comment: sadly the second query does not work for me, it throws "Error Code: 1111. Invalid use of group function"

Answer (score 4):

See below, its working.

```
SELECT userId, sum(Amount) as 'Total'
FROM Orders 
GROUP BY userId 
ORDER BY Total DESC
LIMIT 1
```

Output is

```
+++++++++++++++
userId + Total
+++++++++++++++
2      + 12
+++++++++++++++
```

I also tried after adding new row as

`insert into Orders values (9,1,0,'2010-12-10 12:12:12',10)`

Output is

```
+++++++++++++++
userId + Total
+++++++++++++++
1      + 21
+++++++++++++++
```

Comment: what's the difference between this and my answer?

Comment: @johntotetwoo : I didn't saw your query even... I just tested and answered here...

Comment: @johntotetwoo : And adding new data and testing is enough to tell you that I tested at my end... Gotcha???

Comment: I already reversed my vote anyway it does not matter at all. Good day!

Answer (score 3):

I prefer to have this solution

```
SELECT UserID, SUM(AMOUNT) as TotalAmount
FROM Orders
GROUP BY UserID
having SUM(AMOUNT) = (select sum(amount) as col1
                 from orders
                 group by userid
                 order by  col1 desc
                 limit 1
                 )
```

This sql will show all users who have max purchases

Just try to change amount of orderid 1 to be 2 , then this sql will show both.